# Glassfish 3.1.1 Creating Domain fails, The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows, domain, installation, glassfish

I tried to install Glassfish 3.1.1 on windows with an installer but the `Config Result` - `Creating Domain` fails.

This is the error message:

```
Executing command :C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile
- create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080
--domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920
domain1

C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile - create-domain
--savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4848 --instanceport 8080 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920
domain1 The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and solved it:

1.Go to asenv.bat file in Glassfish config directory

2.modify line: set AS_JAVA="C:/Program Files(x86)/Java/" to point to your JDK (not JRE!) installation 
3.retry asadmin command